# PRISM RequestNavigate is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I am working PRISM and have 2 regions in XAML MainWindowView:

```
<IG6:SplitPane IG6:XamDockManager.InitialLocation="DockedTop"> 
<IG6:TabGroupPane x:Name="MessageGroupPane" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.MessageGroupPane}">

<IG6:SplitPane IG6:XamDockManager.InitialLocation="DockedBottom"
<IG6:TabGroupPane x:Name="MainContentGroupPane"  prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static inf:RegionNames.MainContentGroupPane}">   

public class InfrastructureModule : IModule
{
    container.RegisterType<IMessageViewVM, MessageViewVM>();
    container.RegisterType<object, MessageView>("MessageView");
    regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.MessageGroupPane, typeof(MessageView));
}
```

When the code executes, ALL views are placed in the last `tabGroupPane` identified in the XAML --in this case the `MainContentGroupPane`-- not in the requested region `MessageGroupPane`.

I am using `TabGroupPaneRegionActiveAwareBehavior` from the examples provided by Brian Lagunas.  Views are shown correctly but I am unable to place them in a specific region.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Just asking the obvious but have you double checked that your RegionNames constants are not messed up? I mean RegionNames.MessageGroupPane is what its supposed to be? (Sometimes copying pasting can cause typos :)

Comment: Hi Jinish, I use constants for the region names.    public static string MessageGroupPane = "MessageGroupPane";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should register in the module the target view *TargetView* for navigation:

```
    container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<TargetView>();
```